# how to kill command line process start with child_process nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

how can i stop it, it keep running after i stop nodejs. I try process.kill() but not working

```
const process = require('child_process')
const child = process.exec('ping 8.8.8.8 -t')
setTimeout(()=>child.kill(2),10000)
```

after a few hour reading nodejs docs, i found this for who have same my problem

```
const process = require('child_process')
const child = process.execFile('ping 8.8.8.8',['-t'],{cwd:'your working direct'})
setTimeout(()=>child.kill(2),10000)//now kill() working
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code as below to flush out the error:

```
const process = require('child_process')
const child = process.spawn('ping 8.8.8.8 -t') // instead of process.exec
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(child.kill(2)) // --> false == failed
}, 10000);

child.on('error', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(`${code}`) // --> Error: spawn ping 8.8.8.8 -t ENOENT
});
```

The ping command requires an argument after the -t ( as per terminal: `ping: option requires an argument -- t`

Comment: is that working for some cli aplication like winrar?

Comment: i want to do something like someappname.exe -(some argument) and i can start or stop it with nodejs

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with windows environments, but you can certainly call an executable using `child_process` module, or any shell script. Here's what I found for windows: (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows)